# How should 'print be printed?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have 13 questions tagged [print](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print), covering:

- Printing to paper, or writing output to a file that is meant to be printed on paper (PDF or PostScript): [1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-to-specify-a-printer) [2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12414/how-can-i-print-an-emacs-frame) [3](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18407/ps-print-buffer-with-faces-with-color-themeed-dark-background) [4](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/lpr-print-only-part-of-text) [5](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24552/how-to-print-a-pdf-displayed-with-pdf-tools-from-emacs) [6](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18577/printing-umlauts)
- Converting a Lisp object to a string representation: [1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27765/get-a-better-printed-representation-of-a-hash-table)
- The `print` function and its siblings: [1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18293/functions-print-outputs-twice-the-expected-output) [2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24787/temporarily-suppressing-standard-output) [3](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23896/can-i-print-output-to-stderr-in-batch-mode-without-a-trailing-newline)
  [4](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27338/lisp-form-print-depth)

I propose to rename the tag to “printing” for the printing-to-paper/PDF/… meaning, because that's the tag name most SE sites use.

What about the other questions? Is there a unifying tag name for the other two meanings?

Answer (score 4):

I agree that `printing` makes sense for the printing-to-paper/PDF questions.

For the others (convert to string representation, and the `print` function), my first reaction is to switch them over to the `elisp` tag.

I realize that the `elisp` tag is sometimes vague/abused (we had a meta discussion about it a while back), but these topics seem like they're close enough to elisp-the-language to fit.  I'm not a fan of proliferating separate tags for different elisp functions, and would prefer not to add to the babel.